# On a phrase that combines "can be" and "no longer"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Can someone answer which one is correct between

- can no longer be

or

- can be no longer

---

Example)

> The cars can no longer be used as public vehicles.
>
> The cars can be no longer used as public vehicles.

Are the both common?

Comment: I've commonly seen the usage of "can no longer be"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both proper grammar, but personally I see people use:

> The cars can no longer be used as public vehicles.

More of the time.

Comment: "Can be no longer" is [virtually nonexistent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+no+longer+be%2C+can+be+no+longer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20no%20longer%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20be%20no%20longer%3B%2Cc0) in modern English.

Comment: @U10-Forward Do you mean **They're both......**